# Don't deserialise property (set value to be raw serialised data)

Tags: c#, .net, json, jsonserializer

When deserialization an object is there an easy way to tell the deserializer "don't serialise the content of this property, whatever the serialised data looks like, dump that into this property"
(And obviously the reverse when serializing)

So I have a class which is being deserialized from JSON (deserialization was started automatically by .NET when a web method was called that uses this type).
Most of the data in the incoming JSON packet is used by server-side code but this one property is only ever used by the client.

The server-side code has no need to know the contents, or even the format of this property - it should be treated as a black box simply to be copied around as-is and the returned to the client at the appropriate time.

If I set the property's type as string deserialization fails as it tries to set a property on the string object.
If I set the property's type as object then it contains a partially deserialized dictionary object.

The dictionary object would be fine if the overall object only ever exists in memory, but in fact the whole object then gets reserialized to xml [don't ask, suffice to say XSLT].

I can implement the serialization of the property to xml (or just back to JSON and store that in the xml) but this seems like wasted effort.

Some chunks of code -

The class:

```
public class MyClass : IMyserializationInterface
{
  public string PropertyThatShouldBeDeserializedAsNormal {get;set;}
  [SomeAttr] public object PropertyThatShouldNotBeDeserialized {get;set;}
  public void Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer, MySerializer customSerializer)
  {
        customSerializer.DefaultDeSerialize<MyClass>(this, dictionary, serializer);
        customSerializer.PropagateParent(this);
  }
```

The Interface:

```
  public interface IMyserializationInterface
  {
    void Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, 
                     System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer, 
                     MySerializer customSerializer);
    IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer, MySerializer customSerializer);
  }
```

The Serializer:

```
public class MySerializer: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptConverter
{
   //class processes some attributes to decide what to de/serialize
   //methods in the class are supplied with the already part-deserialized dictionary object
   //what we really need is the raw JSON
}
```

web.config:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization>
          <converters>
            <add name="IMyserializationInterface" type="MySerializer"/>
          </converters>
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

The JSON:

```
{
  "PropertyThatShouldBeDeserializedAsNormal":"SomeString",
  "PropertyThatShouldNotBeDeserialized": {"An":"Object"}
}
```

I'm looking for a low-overhead way to simply skip the Deserialization process for a specific property - i.e. so that `PropertyThatShouldNotBeDeserialized` would contain the string `{"An":"Object"}`

Comment: Sorry for the lengthy question!

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question asks how to remove a property from serialization entirely, which would leave the property value as NULL - which is not what I want to do.

Comment: That would require a specialized serialization. You'd have to code the serialization yourself.